# (mis) understanding `first` in `xts`

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to use the `xts` function `first` to look at the first week or two of my `xts` object. I've used `first` before and it behaves as expected. Here's a well behaved example:

```
library(quantmod)                                                                                
getSymbols('IBM', from='2000-01-01', to='2000-12-31')                                            
first(IBM, "week")  

#>            IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted
#> 2000-01-03 112.4375 116.0000 111.875  116.0000   10347700     81.97214
#> 2000-01-04 114.0000 114.5000 110.875  112.0625    8227800     79.18969
#> 2000-01-05 112.9375 119.7500 112.125  116.0000   12733200     81.97214
#> 2000-01-06 118.0000 118.9375 113.500  114.0000    7971900     80.55885
#> 2000-01-07 117.2500 117.9375 110.625  113.5000   11856700     80.20554

first(IBM, "2 weeks")                                                                            
#>            IBM.Open IBM.High IBM.Low IBM.Close IBM.Volume IBM.Adjusted
#> 2000-01-03 112.4375 116.0000 111.875  116.0000   10347700     81.97214
#> 2000-01-04 114.0000 114.5000 110.875  112.0625    8227800     79.18969
#> 2000-01-05 112.9375 119.7500 112.125  116.0000   12733200     81.97214
#> 2000-01-06 118.0000 118.9375 113.500  114.0000    7971900     80.55885
#> 2000-01-07 117.2500 117.9375 110.625  113.5000   11856700     80.20554
#> 2000-01-10 117.2500 119.3750 115.375  118.0000    8540500     83.38549
#> 2000-01-11 117.8750 121.1250 116.625  119.0000    7873300     84.09212
#> 2000-01-12 119.6250 122.0000 118.250  119.5000    6803800     84.44543
#> 2000-01-13 119.9375 121.0000 115.750  118.2500    8489700     83.56213
#> 2000-01-14 120.9375 123.3125 117.500  119.6250   10956600     84.53379
```

That is completely in line with my expectations. However I have this other `xts` object which I created in another project. The only difference (That I know of) is that the values were merged with another data set and interpolated with a spline so that there is a value for the first of each month. So instead of starting on Jan 3, this object starts on Jan 1 (but is still missing the 2nd). It's a bit tricky to recreate with steps, so I'll just read it in here:

```
tst <-                                                                                           
structure(c(78.5624741277677, 81.972145, 79.18969, 81.972145,                                    
80.558853, 80.205544, 83.38549, 84.092117, 84.445427, 83.562126,                                 
84.533791, 81.795456, 84.445427, 84.092117, 85.858765, 85.858765,                                
84.180458, 82.502182, 80.205544, 78.836357, 79.322182, 77.732201,                                
80.205544, 82.767128, 81.707153, 80.647171, 84.048004, 83.031113,                                
84.269081, 81.616318, 82.102638, 82.854218, 81.881592, 82.589005,                                
79.58252, 78.521446, 76.929787, 78.167717, 76.399216, 73.923332,                                 
72.685371), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "FRED",
updated = structure(1530873556.5857, class = c("POSIXct",                                        
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), index = structure(c(946684800,                              
946857600, 946944000, 947030400, 947116800, 947203200, 947462400,                                
947548800, 947635200, 947721600, 947808000, 948153600, 948240000,                                
948326400, 948412800, 948672000, 948758400, 948844800, 948931200,                                
949017600, 949276800, 949363200, 949449600, 949536000, 949622400,                                
949881600, 949968000, 950054400, 950140800, 950227200, 950486400,                                
950572800, 950659200, 950745600, 950832000, 951177600, 951264000,                                
951350400, 951436800, 951696000, 951782400), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(41L,      
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "ibm"))
```

Now when I do a `first` on the data I don't get what I would expect:

```
first(tst, "week")                                                                               
#>                 ibm
#> 2000-01-01 78.56247
```

Just one value? What about if we look at the first two weeks?

```
first(tst, "2 weeks")                                                                            
#>                 ibm
#> 2000-01-01 78.56247
#> 2000-01-03 81.97214
#> 2000-01-04 79.18969
#> 2000-01-05 81.97214
#> 2000-01-06 80.55885
#> 2000-01-07 80.20554
```

Ok, that gives exactly 1 week of data. If I try `3 weeks` I get the first 14 days of the month.

What's going on here? It seems that the only thing that changed is adding an observation for the first of the month to my data yet it has really impacted the behavior of `first` in a way I don't grok. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the trouble simply comes because "week" is not a well-defined unit of time. (`?strftime` alone lists three possible definitions.) `format(as.Date("2000-1-1")+0:10, "%U")` shows that 1 Jan 2000 was the only day of the first week of 2000, according to the US convention. (I don't use `xts`, so this is only a guess.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, xts uses ISO 8601 internally. This means that 2000-01-01 doesn't fall in week 1 but in week 52. Hence if you use `first(tst, "week")` you get the data back for the first week in your data, which is week 52 and only contains 1 record.

If you do:

```
lubridate::isoweek(tst)
 [1] 52  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  9  9
```

You can see that the first date starts in week 52, which matches the outcome from xts.

Also `to.weekly(tst)` will show you that 2000-01-01 uses only the data from 1 day and the next week is based on the data from 2000-01-03 to 2000-01-07.